# Virtualbox proper network configuration

Tags: linux, macos, networking, virtualbox, centos

I'm trying to setup Centos 6.5 on Mac OSX so that:

- CentOS can use internet using NAT mode adapter 1 (eth0)
- Host (Mac OSX) can connect to Guest (CentOS) using static ip via Host Only mode adapter 2 (eth1)

Did everything [like on this blog](http://webees.me/installing-centos-6-4-in-virtualbox-and-setting-up-host-only-networking/) until `ping google.com` from inside CentOS. Neither ping 8.8.8.8 nor ping google.com doesn't return any packet. CentOS has no connection with internet. But static ip works. I can connect to centos using static ip.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the gateway IP of CentOS your host?

Comment: @adampski in which file?

Comment: I haven't used CentOS in about year, and even that was my first time, but typically in `/etc/network/interfaces`? *Edit* I must correct myself, you can configure your VM's NIC within the VM manager. What's your VM manager? I hope I'm right in assuming you're using a VM...